# SQL Server Check Like Constraint for letters and numbers, and a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, constraints

I'm creating a simple constraint on a table's column which only accepts 3 capital letters for the first three letters, a dash "-" and six numbers which follow. So far my inserts have been rejected because of it:

My constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE EQUIPOS
ADD CONSTRAINT NOMBRE CHECK (idEnlace like('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))
GO
```

Trigger for all caps:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_UPPER_NOMBRE 
ON EQUIPOS 
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO equipos
SELECT   UPPER(I.codEquipo),I.marcaEquipo,I.fchEquipo,I.vtoEquipo,I.idEnlace
FROM INSERTED I
END
GO
```

edit: Example of something that should be valid:

```
'JHS-929323'
```

something that should be invalid

```
'JHs-929323'
'JHS-99323'
'JHS929323'
```

I think the constraint is wrong. What comes after Like isn't properly being validated. Any suggestions for anyone who's done something similar before?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Though I notice the column you are converting to upper case is different from the one with the check constraint.

Comment: why do i get downvoted for my questions? not that i care, but curious so i could probably ask in a better fashion.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. You just stated a requirement and dumped some code. Nor did you provide a MVCE of whatever issue you are having with that code.

Comment: @mitbanip: not my downvote, but you didn't provide any means to reproduce the error. Post the query, expected behavior and observed behavior. "Here's my query, I want the query do this, but it does that instead".

Comment: Understood. Will try a bit harder in the future with your suggestions. I just thought it was a common enough issue with a simple answer that I simply could not research.

Answer (score 1):

Create a constraint something like this....

```
ALTER TABLE EQUIPOS
ADD CONSTRAINT NOMBRE CHECK 
      ( 
      LEFT(idEnlace,3) = UPPER(LEFT(idEnlace,3)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
      AND SUBSTRING(idEnlace,4,1) = '-'
      AND RIGHT(idEnlace,6) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
      AND LEN(idEnlace) = 10
      )
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(ID INT identity(1,1), FirstCol VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT FirstCol CHECK (FirstCol LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/M%' 
or FirstCol LIKE '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/F%'))
```